# Не выполняется команда git remote show hub

Tags: php, git, ssh

При попытке привязать hub-репозиторий к prime репозиторию появляется ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

hub-репозиторий расположен по адресу: `/root/site_hub.git:`. Prime находится по адресу `/var/www/anton/data/www/....com/.git`

hub-репозиторий создан с директивой `--bare`.

Что может означать ошибка

> error: cannot run git-upload-pack '/root/site_hub.git': No such file or directory

В директории `/root/site_hub.git/objects/pack` никаких файлов нет.
По ssh захожу под рутом. 
Все как в статье: https://habrahabr.ru/post/127213/

Comment: Забудьте про этот мрак, лучше выучите команду `git worktree`, и пользуйтесь ветками. Если коротко, то идея такая. Создаём основной репозиторий hub (BARE), в нём делаем worktree на то место, которое у вас называется prime от ветки prime. Всё. Никаких remote, никакого геморроя.